# VMware BSOD 0x07

Tags: vmware-workstation

Long story short - was running Win 7 on VMware for a while, then decided to install an antivirus, ran a scan, and it now BSODs on me.

What I've tried - fixed MBR, ran chkdsk, removed the antivirus, reinstalled SCSI controller driver.

Can't boot into safe mode, as it stops on agp440.sys driver. Also I can't get a minidump for Win7, as the control settings / and regedit changes are not saved - I'm running a livecd.

Here's the mem dump from WinDbg, which points to the ntkrpamp.exe fault. Would appreciate if someone could give pointers as to what I can try here.

DUMP:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE (7b)

During the initialization of the I/O system, it is possible that the driver
for the boot device failed to initialize the device that the system is
attempting to boot from, or it is possible for the file system that is
supposed to read that device to either fail its initialization or to simply
not recognize the data on the boot device as a file system structure that
it recognizes.  In the former case, the argument (#1) is the address of a
Unicode string data structure that is the ARC name of the device from which
the boot was being attempted.  In the latter case, the argument (#1) is the
address of the device object that could not be mounted.

If this is the initial setup of the system, then this error can occur if
the system was installed on an unsupported disk or SCSI controller.  Note
that some controllers are supported only by drivers which are in the Windows
Driver Library (WDL) which requires the user to do a custom install.  See
the Windows Driver Library for more information.

This error can also be caused by the installation of a new SCSI adapter or
disk controller or repartitioning the disk with the system partition.  If
this is the case, on x86 systems the boot.ini file must be edited or on ARC
systems setup must be run.  See the "Advanced Server System Administrator's
User Guide" for information on changing boot.ini.

If the argument is a pointer to an ARC name string, then the format of the
first two (and in this case only) longwords will be:

    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR Buffer;

That is, the first longword will contain something like 00800020 where 20
is the actual length of the Unicode string, and the next longword will
contain the address of buffer.  This address will be in system space, so
the high order bit will be set.

If the argument is a pointer to a device object, then the format of the first
word will be:

    USHORT Type;

That is, the first word will contain a 0003, where the Type code will ALWAYS
be 0003.

Note that this makes it immediately obvious whether the argument is a pointer
to an ARC name string or a device object, since a Unicode string can never
have an odd number of bytes, and a device object will always have a Type
code of 3.

Arguments:

Arg1: 8078db58, Pointer to the device object or Unicode string of ARC name
Arg2: c0000034, (reserved)
Arg3: 00000000, (reserved)
Arg4: 00000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1
TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1
DUMP_CLASS: 1
DUMP_QUALIFIER: 402
BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7600.16385.x86fre.win7_rtm.090713-1255
DUMP_TYPE:  0
BUGCHECK_P1: ffffffff8078db58
BUGCHECK_P2: ffffffffc0000034
BUGCHECK_P3: 0
BUGCHECK_P4: 0
CPU_COUNT: 1
CPU_MHZ: f48
CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel
CPU_FAMILY: 6
CPU_MODEL: 9e
CPU_STEPPING: 9
CPU_MICROCODE: 6,9e,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 70'00000000 (cache) 0'00000000 (init)
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT
BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7B
PROCESS_NAME:  System
CURRENT_IRQL:  0
ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-IILFEPS
ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  07-20-2018 14:29:43.0232
ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17134.12 x86fre
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 8302db92 to 8303eff8
STACK_TEXT:  
8078d6f4 8302db92 00001000 00000000 8078d754 hal!READ_PORT_USHORT+0x8
8078d704 8302dcfb 82cf2ec8 04d6b88a 82d40004 hal!HalpCheckPowerButton+0x2e
8078d708 82cf2ec8 04d6b88a 82d40004 00000000 hal!HaliHaltSystem+0x7
8078d754 82cf3d61 00000004 00000000 c0000034 nt!KiBugCheckDebugBreak+0x73
8078db18 82c1c10d 0000007b 8078db58 c0000034 nt!KeBugCheck2+0xa7f
8078db74 82fc1e85 8080a4d8 82fc2ea7 00000000 nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+0x13f
8078dbe4 82fc3757 8080a4d8 8080f7c8 8080a4d8 nt!IopInitializeBootDrivers+0x4ce
8078dc6c 82fc8e6f 0080a4d8 853498b8 853ee020 nt!IoInitSystem+0x5ba
8078dd48 82da147c 8078dd90 82e2466d 8080a4d8 nt!Phase1InitializationDiscard+0xce4
8078dd50 82e2466d 8080a4d8 04d6b24e 00000000 nt!Phase1Initialization+0xd
8078dd90 82cd60d9 82da146f 8080a4d8 00000000 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x9e
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 nt!KiThreadStartup+0x19

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  c52705e91fd7e0732d9f6441d5450a46f91a9b35
THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  7ca3870a8bc4634d73bd1d9c2cc7332f83f4d934
THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  a62e82acce9780aeb71ca7a040a198569eeb8e97
FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  24448dcc
SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  5
SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+13f
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: nt
IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrpamp.exe
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc007
IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7600.16385
STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7B_nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+13f
BUCKET_ID:  0x7B_nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+13f
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x7B_nt!PnpBootDeviceWait+13f
TARGET_TIME:  2018-07-19T15:33:25.000Z
OSBUILD:  7600
OSSERVICEPACK:  16385
SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0
OS_REVISION: 0
SUITE_MASK:  272
PRODUCT_TYPE:  1
OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86
OSNAME:  Windows 7
OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS
OS_LOCALE:  
USER_LCID:  0
OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2009-07-14 02:15:19
BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  090713-1255
BUILDLAB_STR:  win7_rtm
BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7600.16385.x86fre.win7_rtm.090713-1255
ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  3ab
ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM
FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x7b_nt!pnpbootdevicewait+13f
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {4e88c8dd-ed64-d78d-36b0-09671c7316ee}
Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Comment: So you mean that you have a Windows 7 guest install AV in the guest, and the guest is now hitting the BSOD?

Comment: That's right. I've removed the folders and registry values for AV though.